# XSLT trouble with displaying merit badges

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having trouble trying to display ALL the merit badges 1 scout has... And I can't figure out a working solution. For example, I want it to display like this (with line breaks):

```
First Aid
Swimming
Life saving
...
```

So far, it is only displaying the first for each scout, which is first aid

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE bsa SYSTEM "assign08.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="assign08.xsl"?>
<bsa>
  <council name = "jedi">
    <troop number = "01" unitname= "ok">
  <scout>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>
    <phone>111-111-1111</phone>
    <address>
      <street>Fork St.</street>
      <city>Portland</city>
      <state>OR</state>
      </address>
    <rank date-earned = "1/1/01">Eagle</rank>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "1/1/00">First Aid</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "2/1/00">Swimming</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "3/1/00">Life Saving</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "4/1/00">Environmental Science</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "5/1/00">Camping</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "6/1/00">Cooking</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "7/1/00">Safety</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "8/1/00">Basket Weaving</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "9/1/00">Wood carving</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "10/1/00">Archery</meritbadge>
    </scout>
  <scout>
    <firstname>Bill</firstname>
    <lastname>Joel</lastname>
    <phone>111-111-1112</phone>
    <address>
      <street>Fork St.</street>
      <city>Portland</city>
      <state>OR</state>
      </address>
    <rank date-earned = "2/2/02">Eagle</rank>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "1/1/00">First Aid</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "2/1/00">Swimming</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "3/1/00">Life Saving</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "4/1/00">Environmental Science</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "5/1/00">Camping</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "6/1/00">Cooking</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "7/1/00">Safety</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "8/1/00">Basket Weaving</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "9/1/00">Wood carving</meritbadge>
    <meritbadge date-earned = "10/1/00">Archery</meritbadge>
    </scout>
```

...

And here is the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>Buy Scouts of America</h2>
<table border="1">
 <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
   <th>Last Name</th>
     <th>First Name</th>
   <th>Phone Number</th>
     <th>Address</th>
     <th>Rank</th>
     <th>Merit Badges</th>
 </tr>
 <xsl:for-each select="bsa/council/troop/scout">
  <xsl:sort select="lastname"/>
 <tr>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="lastname"/></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="address"/></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="rank"/></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="meritbadge"/></td>
 </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using XSLT 1.0 and `xsl:value-of`. In 1.0, `xsl:value-of` is only going to give you the value of the first occurrence.

Try using `<xsl:apply-templates select="meritbadge"/>` instead. If you need to change the format of what is being output, add a template that matches `meritbadge` and format however you like. Example:

```
<xsl:template match="meritbadge">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

Also (unrelated) you have "Buy Scouts of America" instead of "**Boy** Scouts of America".

**EDIT** - Full example of modified XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Buy Scouts of America</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>Merit Badges</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="bsa/council/troop/scout">
                        <xsl:sort select="lastname"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="lastname"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="firstname"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="address"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="rank"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:apply-templates select="meritbadge"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="meritbadge">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT #2** - Separate councils/troops

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Boy Scouts of America</h1>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="council"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="council">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="troop"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="troop">
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="concat(@number,' - ',@unitname)"/></h3>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Rank</th>
                <th>Merit Badges</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="scout">
                <xsl:sort select="lastname"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="scout">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates select="lastname"/></td>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates select="firstname"/></td>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates select="phone"/></td>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates select="address"/></td>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates select="rank"/></td>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates select="meritbadge"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="meritbadge|address/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @CSStudent - Put the template right after the template that matches `/`. I added an example template; let me know if you need a full XSLT. Also, instead of `xsl:for-each` and `xsl:value-of` (pull approach), consider a push approach instead (`xsl:apply-templates` and overriding with additional templates). This is much easier to maintain once your XSLT gets larger.

Comment: I'm sorry, im kinda lost here. Would you mind including the full XSLT? I really don't know where to start anymore

Comment: @CSStudent - I added a modified version of your XSLT. I can add a push example too if you'd like.

Comment: Oh, one more question, how would I separate it into different councils and troops?

Comment: @CSStudent - To separate it into different councils/troops, just add templates to match those and instead of doing a `xsl:for-each` on `bsa/council/troop/scout` in a template that matches `/`, do the `xsl:for-each` on the `council`. I added another example (but using `xsl:apply-templates` instead.

Comment: Im so sorry. Could you do one more example of how I would divide it into a council. I've been trying to use the templates, but it keeps screwing up. Thanks for your help by the way. If I can see a council template done, I can probably do a troop one

Comment: @CSStudent - There should be an example now. I pasted the wrong one earlier.

Comment: Ohhhhhh ok. Wow thank you so much! I understand how to do it now!

Comment: @CSStudent - No problem at all. Hopefully it will start to make sense now.